# Cadastro multiplo de imagem

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Lá venho eu pedir ajuda de vocês novalmente!
Criei uma função para cadastrar imagens no banco de dados sendo uma delas a capa e o restante imagens de album.

O script até cadastra a imagem de capa e do album, porém do album só é cadastrada no banco 1 (uma) imagem, o mais curioso é que os arquivos são movidos para a pasta `uploads/` mas nao sao registrados no banco.

O HTML:

```
<?php //Chama a função inserir caso tenha algum dado em POST (includes/conexao)
   if (isset($_POST['salvar'])) {
   criar_album('albumImagens', 'capa', $_POST);
}  
?>

<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" runat="server" />
<fieldset>

 <legend>Nova imagem</legend>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="nome">Nome</label>  
   <div class="col-md-6">
  <input name="nome" type="text" placeholder class="form-control input-md" required />
   </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Text input --> 
  <div class="form-group">   
    <div id="thumbnail">
   </div>
   <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="capa">Capa:</label>  
   <div class="col-md-4">
  <input type="file" name="capa" id="capa" class="form-control" required>
</div>
   </div>

   <!-- Text input-->
   <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="imagem">Album:</label>  
   <div class="col-md-4">
  <input type="file" name="imagem[]" id="imagem" class="form-control" required multiple />
   </div>
   </div>

   <!-- Button -->
   <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="salvar"></label>
   <div class="col-md-5">
  <button type="submit" id="salvar" name="salvar" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Salvar</button>
   </div>
   </div>

   </fieldset>
   </form>
```

A function:

```
function criar_album($album, $destaque, $dados){
$con = conectar();
$caminho = 'uploads/';
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$qtd = count($_FILES["imagem"]["name"]);

if ($qtd > 0){
   $nomeArquivoCapa = $_FILES["capa"]["name"];
   $nomeTemporarioCapa = $_FILES["capa"]["tmp_name"];
   $tamanhoArquivoCapa = $_FILES["capa"]["size"];

for ($i=0; $i <= $qtd; $i++) { 
    $nomeArquivo = $_FILES["imagem"]["name"][$i];
    $nomeTemporario = $_FILES["imagem"]["tmp_name"][$i];
    $tamanhoArquivo = $_FILES["imagem"]["size"][$i];


    if (!empty($nomeArquivoCapa)) {
        $arquivoArrayCapa = explode(".", $nomeArquivoCapa);
        $extensaoCapa = end($arquivoArrayCapa);
        $arquivoCapa = $caminho.md5(time().rand(3212, 15452)).'.'.$extensaoCapa;

        if (move_uploaded_file($nomeTemporarioCapa, $arquivoCapa)) {
            $inserir = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO $destaque(nome, imagem) VALUES('$nome', '$arquivoCapa')");
            $inseri = $inserir->execute(); // Execute a inserção
            $last = $con->lastInsertId();
        }

        if (!empty($nomeArquivo)) {
        $arquivoArray = explode(".", $nomeArquivo);
        $extensao = end($arquivoArray);
        $arquivo = $caminho.md5(time().rand(3212, 15452)).'.'.$extensao;

        if (move_uploaded_file($nomeTemporario, $arquivo)) {
        $inserir = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO $album(idCapa, imagem) VALUES('$last', '$arquivo')");
        $inseri = $inserir->execute(); // Execute a inserção    
        }

    else {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Erro, tente novamente mais tarde!</div>';
        }
    }   
}

    }
echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Salvo com sucesso!</div>';
  }
}
```

Estrutura SQL:

Tabela `capa`:
ID, Nome e imagem

Tabela `albumImagens`:
idCapa, imagem

O que parece que acontece é que o for não esta funcionando, pois ele só faz uma passagem e nada mais.
O trecho `if (move_uploaded_file($nomeTemporario, $arquivo))`
Esta movendo todas as imagens de uma vez ao meu ver...

> Executei um `var_dump($inserir)` para ver se as `querys` estam sendo
>   geradas e notei que estão sendo geradas SIM porem o execute só
>   acontece  `UMA VEZ` inserindo apenas 1 imagem no banco de dados.

```
object(PDOStatement)#3 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(101) "INSERT INTO albumImagens(idCapa, imagem) VALUES('59', 'uploads/16487b1c9236bca1231deafb2e711d15.png')" } object(PDOStatement)#1 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(101) "INSERT INTO albumImagens(idCapa, imagem) VALUES('59', 'uploads/7cb40a35907252ef2e0c401bc0561b1c.png')" }
```

Apenas a imagem 1 com final `11d15.jpg` esta sendo inserida...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na hora de desenvolver um projeto, ou criar um script auxiliar, é essencial estar calmo acima de tudo, porque escrever códigos com mais de `100` linhas já começa a ser um bocado complicado na hora de encontrar `}`, ou `;` no meio de tantas funções, variáveis e argumentos, no teu código, confesso que não foi diferente, acima de tudo não tinha `notas` o que costuma a ser bom às vezes até mesmo para o próprio autor do código.

O que se segue são algumas possíveis melhorias que introduzi no teu `script`, de modo a tornar mais objetivo/eficiente.

## Funções

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO("mysql: hostname=localhost; dbname=example;", "root", "");

// Nesta função trabalhamos uma vez mais a array, de modo a obtermos a mesma ID
function array_final($array, $id){
    if(is_array($array)){
        foreach($array as $im){
            $f[] =  array("imagem"=>$im, "id"=>$id);
        }   
        $valores = array();
        foreach($f as $p){
            $valores = array_merge($valores, array_values($p));
        }
        return $valores;
    } else {
        return false;   
    }
}

function imagens($array, $nome=null){
    if(!empty($array) && isset($array)){
        // Esta linha imprime o nome dos ficheiros em maiusculo, para o caso de $nome for diferente de vazio    
        if(isset($nome)){
            // Para multiplos ficheiros (album) 
            if(is_array($array["name"])){
                foreach($array["name"] as $id=>$item){
                    $imagem[] = $item;  
                }   
            // Para o caso de o ficheiro selecionado  ser apenas 1 (CAPA)   
            } else {
                $explode = explode(".", $array["name"]);    
                return strtoupper($explode[0]); 
            }
            if(isset($imagem)){
                foreach($imagem as $id=>$img){
                    $explode[] = explode(".", $img);
                }   
                for($i=0; $i<count($explode);$i++){
                    $explodes[] = strtoupper(array_shift($explode[$i]));    
                }
                // Retorna uma array contento o nome e a extensao dos arquivos  
                return $explodes;   
            }   
        // Para o caso de $nome for igual a  0, ou vazio    
        } else {
            // Para multiplos ficheiros (album)     
            if(is_array($array["name"])){
                foreach($array["name"] as $id=>$item){
                    $imagem[] = $item;  
                }
            // Para o caso de o ficheiro selecionado  ser apenas 1 (CAPA)       
            } else {
                return $array["name"];  
            }
            if(isset($imagem)){
                // Retorna uma array contento o nome e a extensao dos arquivos  
                return $imagem; 
            }   
        }
    } else {
        return false;   
    }   
}

function enviar($ficheiro, $caminho){
    // Arquivo existe ? 
    if(count($ficheiro) <= 0){
        return false;   
    } else {
        // Para multiplos ficheiros (album)         
        if(is_array($ficheiro["name"])){
            foreach($ficheiro["name"] as $id=>$imagem){
                $upload = $caminho . basename($imagem);
                $estado = move_uploaded_file($ficheiro["tmp_name"][$id], $upload) ? true : false;   
            }   
        // Para o caso de o ficheiro selecionado  ser apenas 1 (CAPA)       
        } else {
            $upload = $caminho . basename($ficheiro["name"]);
            $estado = move_uploaded_file($ficheiro["tmp_name"], $upload) ? true : false;    
        }
        // se o ficheiro for movido com sucesso, retorna true como ultima declaracao
        if($estado == true){
            return true;    
        }   
    }   
}

function criar_album($album, $capa){
// chamar a váriavel pdo atravez do escopo global       
global $pdo;
// Caminho/diretorio para onde vao os ficheiros
$caminho = 'up/';
$qtd = count($_FILES["imagem"]["name"]);

if ($qtd > 0){
       $nomeArquivoCapa = $_FILES["capa"]["name"];
       $upload = $caminho . basename($nomeArquivoCapa);
       // Se o ficheiro de capa e o(s) ficheiro(s) forem movidos com sucesso
       if(enviar($_FILES["capa"], $caminho, "capa") && enviar($_FILES["imagem"], $caminho, "imagem")){
            // Prepara a primeira consulta SQL 
           $inserir = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO {$capa} (nome, imagem) VALUES (:nome, :imagem)");
           // Passando multiplos parametros atravez do metodo execute do PDO
           // inserir->execute(array(":bind1"=>valor1, "bind2"=>valor2, ...));
           $inserir->execute(array(":nome"=>imagens($_FILES["capa"], 1), ":imagem"=>imagens($_FILES["capa"])));
           // Captar a ultima ID inseriida
           $id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
            // Aqui iniciamos uma transação para maior fluidez  
           $pdo->beginTransaction();
           // calcular o numero de placeholders para a query em questao
           foreach(imagens($_FILES["imagem"]) as $p){
               $interr[] = '(?,?)';
           }
            // Aqui concatenamos os valores anteriormente trabalhados, incluindo os placeholders
           $sql = "INSERT INTO {$album} (imagem, idCapa) VALUES ". implode(",", $interr);   
           echo $sql;
           // Preparar a consulta SQL
           $inserir = $pdo->prepare($sql);
           try{
           // Executar a consulta, com multiplos parametros
           // INSERT INTO tabela (campo1, campo2) VALUES (?,?),(?,?)...
                $inserir->execute(array_final(imagens($_FILES["imagem"]), $id));
           // Capturar a exceção        
           } catch (PDOException $e){
           // Imprimir a exceção, se existir        
                $e->getMessage();
           }
           // Confirmar inclusao 
           $pdo->commit();
      } 
    }
}

?>
```

Para este caso, o que se queria, era cadastrar no banco de dados, um conjunto de valores de uma só vez.
No entanto era necessário construir uma `query` desse gênero:

> INSERT INTO tabela (campo1, campo2) VALUES (?, ?), (?, ?)...

Uma vez que se trabalhou com `placeholders` colocou-se então os `pontos de interrogação` no lugar onde seriam substituídos os valores.

Sendo que o conjunto de resultados para a consulta efetuada foi algo assim:

```
Array ( [0] => usr1.jpg [1] => 55 [2] => usr2.jpg [3] => 55 ) 

               (imagem)       (id)       (imagem)       (id)
```

Segundo o [site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-speed.html) realizar consulta utilizando esse processo pode vir até a ser mais rápido que as habituais.

> Acima de tudo, só espero não ter-te complicado a vida com essas
>   funções novas que adicionei, não tarda edito a minha resposta e
>   adiciono mais alguns detalhes a explicar o que se estava a passar com
>   o teu código original, ou como solucionar o problema nele.

## Script Original

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO("mysql: hostname=localhost; dbname=example;", "root", "");

function criar_album($album, $capa){
global $pdo;
$caminho = 'up/';
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$qtd = count($_FILES["imagem"]["name"]);

if ($qtd > 0){
   $nomeArquivoCapa = $_FILES["capa"]["name"];
   $nomeTemporarioCapa = $_FILES["capa"]["tmp_name"];
   $tamanhoArquivoCapa = $_FILES["capa"]["size"];

for ($i=0; $i < $qtd; $i++) { 
    $nomeArquivo = $_FILES["imagem"]["name"][$i];
    $nomeTemporario = $_FILES["imagem"]["tmp_name"][$i];
    $tamanhoArquivo = $_FILES["imagem"]["size"][$i];


    if (!empty($nomeArquivoCapa)) {
        $arquivoArrayCapa = explode(".", $nomeArquivoCapa);
        $extensaoCapa = end($arquivoArrayCapa);
        $arquivoCapa = $caminho.md5(time().rand(3212, 15452)).'.'.$extensaoCapa;
        // Descomente a linha para guardar a imagem com o nome original no banco de dados
        //$arquivo = $nomeArquivoCapa;

        if (move_uploaded_file($nomeTemporarioCapa, $arquivoCapa)) {
            $inserir = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO $capa(nome, imagem) VALUES('$nome', '$arquivoCapa')");
            $inseri = $inserir->execute(); // Execute a inserção
            $last = $pdo->lastInsertId();
        }

        if (!empty($nomeArquivo)) {
        $arquivoArray = explode(".", $nomeArquivo);
        $extensao = end($arquivoArray);
        $arquivo = $caminho.md5(time().rand(3212, 15452)).'.'.$extensao;
        // Descomente a linha para guardar a imagem com o nome original no banco de dados
        //$arquivo = $nomeArquivo;
        if (move_uploaded_file($nomeTemporario, $arquivo)) {
        $inserir = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO $album(idCapa, imagem) VALUES('$last', '$arquivo')");
        $inseri = $inserir->execute(); // Execute a inserção    
        }

    else {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Erro, tente novamente mais tarde!</div>';
        }
    }   
}

    }
echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Salvo com sucesso!</div>';
  }
}

?>
```

Se fores ler as linhas com atenção, vais reparar que não troquei praticamente nada, apenas `1 sinal` foi removido, o que estava no `looping for`.

De:

```
for ($i=0; $i <= $qtd; $i++) { 
    ...
```

Para:

```
for ($i=0; $i < $qtd; $i++) { 
    ...
```

Mudei também o nome valor da variável caminho, que era `uploads`, para `up`, o resto está a mesma coisa. Confesso que ainda me baralho a tentar entender o teu código.

Contudo, aqui está a realizar o `upload` e `cadastro` com sucesso, restando apenas citar o erro.

O mais provável é que o erro esteja na estrutura da tua tabela. É assim que a(s) minha(s) tabela(s) está(ao) estruturada:

```
--
-- Estrutura da tabela `albumimagens`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `albumimagens` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idCapa` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `imagem` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idCapa` (`idCapa`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=17 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `capa` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `imagem` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=77 ;
```

Apesar dos valores nos campos `varchar` serem insuficientes para a `hash` gerada para o nome das imagens, as imagens estavam a ser salvas à metade.

Outra coisa é, se fores reparar nas minhas duas tabelas, ambas têm um campo `ID` independente `primary key` e com `auto_increment`, que para o caso em questão é obrigatório e noutros, é simplesmente recomendado. Por isso, se possível, apague e crie novamente a tabela `albumimagens` e experimenta novamente.

Até, mais e boa sorte.

## Outras fontes:

[PDO Prepared insert with mult. rows...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176352/pdo-prepared-inserts-multiple-rows-in-single-query)

Comment: Edilson, confesso que ficou muito mais complicado do que meu proprio codigo, voce teve que criar 3 funcões para fazer uma coisa que eu fiz com uma, fiquei muito confuso com algumas linhas...

Comment: Ás vezes para tornar o código mais portável, e mais arrumado, é necessário fazer isso *-*, depois edito e coloco uma resolução/explicação em ordem ao teu código.

Comment: Aí está, espero que desta vez funcione contigo, porque aqui está a funcionar normalmente, mas ainda assim recomendo organizar `loopings` como este, ou declarações demasiado extensas em funções, costuma a ajudar muito.

Comment: Edilson, consegui encontrar o erro! eu não estava criando um id padrão para a tabela `albumimagens`, estava apenas usando o `idCapa`, quando mudei funcionou normalmente, obrigado!

Comment: Ainda bem que conseguiste, é sempre bom trabalhar com calma e prestar atenção em tudo amigo. Boa sorte.

Answer (score 1):

O problema pelo que notei é o seguinte, como você aborda, sua intenção é cadastrar um album com uma imagem de capa e as demais sendo extras. Contudo na sua função atual você tem o `upload` e registro da capa dentro do `loop` for. Assim Você esta cadastrando o album na mesma quantidade de vezes que as ocorrências de imagem.

Para resolver isso é simples basta remover o trecho de código de cadastro do álbum de dentro do for.

```
<?php
function criar_album($album, $destaque, $dados){
    $con = conectar();
    $caminho = 'uploads/';
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $qtd = count($_FILES["imagem"]["name"]);

    if ($qtd > 0){
        $nomeArquivoCapa = $_FILES["capa"]["name"];
        $nomeTemporarioCapa = $_FILES["capa"]["tmp_name"];
        $tamanhoArquivoCapa = $_FILES["capa"]["size"];

        if(empty($nomeArquivoCapa)){
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Erro, capa nao inserida!</div>';
            return;
        }

        $arquivoArrayCapa = explode(".", $nomeArquivoCapa);
        $extensaoCapa = end($arquivoArrayCapa);
        $arquivoCapa = $caminho.md5(time().rand(3212, 15452)).'.'.$extensaoCapa;

        if (move_uploaded_file($nomeTemporarioCapa, $arquivoCapa)) {
            $inserir = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO $destaque(nome, imagem) VALUES('$nome', '$arquivoCapa')");
            $inseri = $inserir->execute(); // Execute a inserção
            $last = $con->lastInsertId();
        }else{
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Erro, tente novamente mais tarde!</div>';
        }

        for ($i=0; $i <= $qtd; $i++) { 
            $nomeArquivo = $_FILES["imagem"]["name"][$i];
            $nomeTemporario = $_FILES["imagem"]["tmp_name"][$i];
            $tamanhoArquivo = $_FILES["imagem"]["size"][$i];

            if (!empty($nomeArquivo)) {
                $arquivoArray = explode(".", $nomeArquivo);
                $extensao = end($arquivoArray);
                $arquivo = $caminho.md5(time().rand(3212, 15452)).'.'.$extensao;

                if (move_uploaded_file($nomeTemporario, $arquivo)) {
                    $inserir = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO $album(idCapa, imagem) VALUES('$last', '$arquivo')");
                    $inseri = $inserir->execute(); // Execute a inserção    
                }else{
                    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Erro, tente novamente mais tarde!</div>';
                }
            }

        }
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Salvo com sucesso!</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Infelizmente ainda continua o mesmo problema, apenas `uma imagem é cadastrada` no banco.

Comment: @RafaelAcioly tente realizar um debug para ver as SQL que estao sendo feitas, e apos verificar se esta salvando com `idCapa` correspondente.

Comment: sim Guilherme, coloquei o código para forçar exibição de erro e o que retornou foi `Notice: Undefined offset: 2` esse erro corresponte a linha logo abaixo do  `for`, referente a inserção do `idCapa` o mesmo acontece normalmente.

Comment: A razão para o `undefined` é que, eu também não notei, como se esta usando `count` ele retorna no a quantidade total de registros. e o array inicia em 0, então o erro esta no `for` que deve ser `$i < $qtd`.

Comment: ainda não resolveu, o problema é na hora de inserir a imagem no banco de dados porque o script esta movendo todas de uma vez e por isso não retorna para o `for`

Comment: Guilherme, fiz um `var_dump($inserir)` (depois da query) e o retorno que tive foi de `2 querys para inserção` ou seja, as querys são criadas mas na hora de executar ele só executa uma...

Comment: Estas duas query esta na mesma string? se sim, verifique se estão separadas por `;`, pois uma deve ser independente da outra.

Comment: Guilherme, coloquei o resultado da query no post, veja o que aparece! parece que não existe o `;`

Comment: @RafaelAcioly ele esta executando um dois momentos separados, desta forma não necessidade do `;`, contudo não consigo pensar em mais nada que possa ser o problema. Uma dica, comentar cada parte do codigo, explicando, quem sabe assim você encontro o erro.